# in VS, how do you use regex find/replace but increment numeric value

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

given that I have an xml tag  like this
A30001

I was able to get a regex going which got me the numeric part - 30001

like this:

```
3{[0-9]^4}\<
```

I can then get the value back by replacing the tagged experession like so

```
3\1<
```

but need to know if visual studio's regex engine will let me replace it with 30002

thanks

Comment: I'm not terribly well acquainted with the quirks of VS regex handling, but I will say that regular expressions have no concept of a number beyond a sequence of digit characters.  Incrementing it as a value (or performing any other mahematical operation) using that tool is probably not possible.

Comment: I don't believe so. You'd need to write code to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the answer is no. After scouring the web, I ended up doing manual replace with the next higher number.